# Installation of QARK in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, security-testing

I've tried to install QARK in my Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop machine. I was following some docs provided by Linked In but it has not worked for me.

Comment: Can you be specific about what isn't working for you? Please [edit] the question in order to add that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prerequisite

Python 2.7.17-1

pip 9.0.1

openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17 (java home environment variable hast to be set)

Download QARK from github

$ git clone https://github.com/linkedin/qark

$ cd qark

$ pip install -r requirements.txt

$ python setup.py install

To test APK :

$ sudo qark --apk path/to/my.apk

It will take some time, the html report will be generating on the following path

/home//.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qark/report/report.html